# How to create a Chord diagram in Python with In- and Output dependencies?

Tags: python, visualization, chord-diagram

I want to create a Chord diagram in Python with following dataframe:

| Message Out | Message In | Signalname |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | M1 |
| A | B | M2 |
| B | C | M3 |
| C | D | M4 |
| C | D | M5 |
| C | D | M6 |

What I find in existing chord diagram solutions is only 2 entities (here Message Out and Message In) with a value/count. What I need is to show also interactivly the Signalname for Input and Output for each entity. Is it possible to create such a Chord Diagram in Python? I saw this in R shiny.
Hope someone can help me.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The [D3Blocks library](https://d3blocks.github.io/d3blocks/pages/html/index.html) can help you make the Chord charts.
An example for your case would be as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

source=['A','A','B','C','E','F']
target=['B','B','C','D','D','D']
weights=[1,1,2,1,1,1]

df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.c_[source, target, weights], columns=['source','target','weight'])
from d3blocks import D3Blocks

# Initialize
# If you set frame=False, you can work with dictionaries
d3 = D3Blocks(frame=True)
d3.chord(df)

# Edit any of the properties you want in the dataframe:
d3.node_properties

#        id label    color  opacity
# label                            
# A       0     A  #1f77b4      0.8
# B       1     B  #2ca02c      0.8
# C       2     C  #9467bd      0.8
# D       3     D  #e377c2      0.8
# E       4     E  #bcbd22      0.8
# F       5     F  #9edae5      0.8

d3.edge_properties
d3.edge_properties['color'].iloc[1]='#000000'

#   source target weight  opacity    color
# 0      A      B      1      0.8  #1f77b4
# 1      A      B      1      0.8  #1f77b4
# 2      B      C      2      0.8  #2ca02c
# 3      C      D      1      0.8  #9467bd
# 4      E      D      1      0.8  #bcbd22
# 5      F      D      1      0.8  #9edae5

# Plot again
d3.show()
```

[image]